# How to bypass automatic load detection on a li-ion charging module?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

Some li-ion charging ICs (like TP4303) have automatic load detection. How does automatic load detection work? In other words, what does the IC detect to come out of stand-by? The goal is to bypass automatic load detection on a charging module.

Comment: Excerpt from TP4303 datasheet (translated form Chinese using Google Translate): 

Load Detection and Low Power Smart Standby:
TP4303 supports load automatic detection mode, when the load is connected, it will automatically call Wake up to charge the load, when the load is unplugged, after 16S delay, the circuit is closed, The IC enters a low-current standby mode, and the standby current is reduced below 20uA.

Comment: Why would you want to bypass load detection?

Comment: I have an AMS1117 3.3V regulator downstream to TP4303 in the circuit; which feeds into a manual on/off push-button switch. The intention is that TP4303 will feed 5V to AMS1117; which in turn will output 3.3V; which in turn will feed the load when switch is pushed. The stand-by current draw of AMS1117 is around 8mA (empirically measured); which doesn't take TP4303 out of stand-by. I found out that this behavior isn't limited to TP4303 only, as other TPower ICs used in charging modules also have this automatic load detection mechanism.

Comment: Why does the AMS1117 need to be powered up all the time? Why not put the switch between it and the TP4303?

Comment: I am trying to replace the power supply side of an appliance which has its own mechanism to switch on and off. Objective is to perform minimal intervention in the device's operational mechanism.